# Bookmarks in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

When I open my CV/Cover letter in Adobe Reader I see that the `\sections` and `\subsections` are in that internal bookmarks. But is it possible to add the cover letter in there, because now it seems like my CV ends after my last `\section` entry on the CV part, but there is still the cover letter on the next page and I also added 2 full page pdf:s as attachments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{classic}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makecvtitle
\section{Stuff 1} %this is on the table of contents
\section{Stuff 2} %this is on the table of contents
\subsection{Minor stuff 2} %this is on the table of contents

\clearpage
\title{Cover letter} %This is not
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\enclosure[Attached]{few pdfs} 

\makelettertitle

\newpage
\clearpage
\includepdf{pdf1} %This is not
\newpage
\clearpage
\includepdf{pdf2} %This is not
\end{document}
```

Id like to add the cover letter and the 2 attached full page pdf:s to the same bookmarks.

Comment: Which Table of Contents?

Comment: Are you talking about the bookmarks in the PDF view?

Comment: Ahh yeah the bookmarks. Sorry didn't know the correct word!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command `\pdfbookmark` provided by `hyperref` (loaded by `moderncv`) and add the bookmarks manually.

For example, just before

```
\makelettertitle
```

put

```
\pdfbookmark{Cover Letter}{Cover}
```

The same can be done before each included `pdf` file.

MWE (I've removed `\newpage`s before `\clearpage`s because have no sense):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makecvtitle
\section{Stuff 1} %this is on the table of contents
\section{Stuff 2} %this is on the table of contents
\subsection{Minor stuff 2} %this is on the table of contents

\clearpage
\title{Cover letter} %This is not
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\enclosure[Attached]{few pdfs}

\pdfbookmark{Cover Letter}{Cover}
\makelettertitle

\clearpage
\pdfbookmark{First PDF}{PDF1}
\includepdf{pdf1} %This is not

\clearpage
\pdfbookmark{Second PDF}{PDF2}
\includepdf{pdf2} %This is not
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
\pdfbookmark[0]{Cover Letter}{CoverLetter}
```

after `\clearpage`:

```
\clearpage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Cover Letter}{CoverLetter}
\title{Cover letter} %This is not
```

Here's what I get in the bookmarks

[image]

The second argument is just a symbolic name, which should be unique.

If you want to add bookmarks for the enclosures, a level under the cover letter,

```
\clearpage
\pdfbookmark[1]{Enclosure 1}{Encl1}
\includepdf{pdf1} %This is not
```

[image]